# Programmatically how do I get at -VM option in eclipse.ini file entries

Tags: java, eclipse

Sorry guys may be a silly question. Eclipse starts by using a .ini file. How do I find the value of -vm in a plugin that I may develop?

Programmatically from my plugin.java code?

Regards,
Jemrug

Comment: Do you mean `System.getProperty("eclipse.vm")`? See also _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_, tab _Configuration_ section `*** System properties:`.

Comment: As mentioned the eclipse.vm property is best, but note that this is not set when you test Eclipse using Run > Eclipse Application. In that case java.home is similar. But why do you want this, it is not normally needed.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. I needed it as I need to be able to run the kinit.exe from the same directory(elcipse.vm) as the java.home may not be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically get the value of `-vm` with **`System.getProperty("eclipse.vm")`**.

See also *Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details*, tab *Configuration* section `*** System properties:`.